# The name "Class1" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, namespaces

I have a problem as in the title
Why file Edycja.xaml in field `<v:Class1 x:Key="con" />` receives an error message

> Error 7 The name ' Class1 ' does not exist in the namespace ' clr- namespace: WpfApplication2 "

I have every using in each files, which required this.

**Edycja.xaml**

```
<Window 
   x:Class="AllSportsBets102.Edycja" 
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
   Title="Edycja" 
   SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" 
   WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
   x:Name="Window" 
   xmlns:v="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2">
   <Window.Resources>
      <v:Class1 x:Key="con" />
   </Window.Resources>
   <Grid>
      <Grid>
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="129*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="47*" />
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=people, ElementName=Window}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
               <DataGridTextColumn Header="ClientName" Binding="{Binding clientName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
               <DataGridTextColumn Header="ClientType" Binding="{Binding clientType}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
               <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Product" Width="120" CanUserSort="False" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding product}" >
                  <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                     <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=clientType,Converter={StaticResource con}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="SelectedValue" Value="{Binding Path=product}"/>
                     </Style>
                  </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                  <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                     <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=clientType,Converter={StaticResource con}}" />
                        <Setter Property="SelectedValue" Value="{Binding Path=product}"/>
                     </Style>
                  </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
               </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
         </DataGrid>
      </Grid>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Class1.cs (this is converter)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AllSportsBets102;
using System.Windows.Data;
namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public class Class1 : IValueConverter
    {
        #region IValueConverter Members

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString()))
            {
                if (value.ToString() == "National")
                    return Edycja.nationalProducts;
                return Edycja.interNationalProducts;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**Edycja.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Net.Mail;
using Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;
using AllSportsBets102.DataGridHelpers;
using AllSportsBets102;
using System.ComponentModel;
namespace AllSportsBets102
{
    public class person
    {
        public string product
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string clientType
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string clientName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public partial class Edycja : Window
    {
        Funkcje FK;
        EdycjaKursow EK;
        public List<string> ListaDyscyplina = new List<string>();
        public List<string> ListaSystemRozgrywek = new List<string>();
        public List<string> ListaKraj = new List<string>();
        public List<string> ListaNazwaLigi = new List<string>();
        public List<string> ListaKolejka = new List<string>();
        public List<string> ListaSystemTypowan = new List<string>();
        public List<string> ListaGospodarze = new List<string>();
        public List<string> ListaGoscie = new List<string>();

        public static List<Data2> dataSourcetmpXXX = new List<Data2>();

        public ObservableCollection<person> people
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public static ObservableCollection<string> nationalProducts
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public static ObservableCollection<string> interNationalProducts
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public Edycja()
        {
            people = new ObservableCollection<person>()
            {
                new person(){product = "a",clientType = "National", clientName="mbt"},
                new person(){product = "p",clientType = "International", clientName="patni"},
                new person(){product = "b",clientType = "National", clientName="igate"},
                new person(){product = "r",clientType = "International", clientName="cgi"}

            };
            nationalProducts = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
            interNationalProducts = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "p", "q", "r", "s", "t" };
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is Class1 marked as public? You said the namespaces were right, but check that Class1 is in the WpfApplication2 namespace and in the same assembly as this xaml file.

Comment: So Class1 is public and Class1 is in the namespace WpfApplication2                      <code> namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public class Class1 : IValueConverter </code>

Comment: Is this error in the XAML parser or is it a build error? Often building will update the underlying symbol file and the error will go away.

Comment: I had some other errors, and after their removal project is launched. Thanks man :)

Comment: Glad to help. I posted my comment as an answer. Feel free to upvote/accept if you think it is useful or would be useful to others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error commonly appears when creating a new class and declaring it in XAML. Try building, and if the error is real it will still be there.

Most often though, this will cause the validation error to go away and your application will be ready to go.